# Helvetica falling back to arial despite the Helvetica.ttf present on my Linux

Tags: html, css, linux, windows, fonts

[My research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461533/helvetica-renders-as-arial-on-windows-os) indicates that for Windows, Helvetica falls back to Arial but is it also true for linux?

**EDIT**

Helvetica.ttf is present on my system. Also on another system where it is not present, the same behavior can be seen.

**EDIT**

Do not know how but this is a comparison between how Firefox rendered it and how Chrome did it (I have erased the non-required parts of the images):

[image: Firefox/Chrome Font Rendering]

As can be seen the first two 'GR' on both browsers are in Helvetica (technically) but only Firefox renders Helvetica, while Chrome does not.

Comment: this link should help https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts

Comment: @wandarkaf - what part of it ?

Comment: you need to install helvetica in linux (ubuntu) and every user need to do this in order to see the helvetica font

Comment: @wandarkaf - What if its there. As stated in the title. Helvetica.ttf is present

Comment: Has Helvetica.ttf been *installed* (not just existing as a file somewhere)? Does it work in other contexts (than web browsers)? Is it a legal copy? How did you deduce that Helvetica falls back to Arial? What are the default fonts in the browsers you tested?

Comment: its not the ttf but some other format(.afm). I do not see the font in the font drop down in LibreOffice Writer. Whether legal or not no idea...but I didnt install it ..so might be legal.It falls back as i saw so in chrome by comparing the same text in Arial.

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not affect Linux computers.

Windows silently maps "Helvetica" to the Arial typeface - this probably a legacy from the time when most web-designers were using Macs, and Mac OS X comes with Helvetica but Windows doesn't, instead it has Microsoft's Helvetica knock-off: Arial. Designers of the time overused Helvetica in their CSS documents without specifying a good fallback for Windows, or even the `sans-serif` fallback family so Windows users would have gotten Time New Roman or some other serif font when it was the baseline default in IE 3.0 and 4 (remember when webpages had grey backgrounds by default, not white?).

Linux isn't Windows, and therefore does not have this problem - instead it has it much worse: (Most) Linux users don't have Helvetica nor Arial installed - so they're very dependent upon CSS authors specifying baseline families (`sans-serif`, `serif`, `monospace`, `fantasy`). But nowadays you can use WOFF to embed fonts in webpages without depending on them being installed, but be careful as fonts are regularly 30KB-300KB in size, or even larger (Chinese-language fonts are often 30MB!).

Comment: 1. this is happening on linux as i mentioned. I searched for Helvetica and can see the .ttf files. I then do <span style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:96px">GR</span><span style="font-family:arial;font-size:96px">GR</span> and yet both the characters come out same for both the families.

Comment: Is this still true? I Mean nowadays there's still no helvetica on modern distros?

Comment: 2."WOFF to embed fonts in webpages without depending on them being installed" - Can we embed Arial and Helvetica? I guess not as then I will need to get the appropriate licenses.Not a good option.

Comment: Where do you see the ttf files?

Comment: @Axel - Thats the point. I have a system which does not have helvetica[Linux] and one Linux which has it installed and yet the characters in Helvetica and Arial are DITTO. No difference even in 'R' and 'G'.

Comment: @Axel- search the / for 'helvetica' and all

Comment: @BhumiSinghal are you sure you have "Helvetica" installed and not any variants like "Helvetica Neue"?

Comment: Use Firebug/DOM Inspector/Chrome Deceloper Tools to see what the "computed style" is for your incorrectly typeset elements.

Comment: @Dai - states Helvetica only.